# How is the Total Virtual Memory Calculated in this server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory, virtual-machines, virtual-memory

From the images below, I am not sure how the 'Total Virtual Memory' available is shown as 7.82 GB in the system information (winmsd.exe) ?

I always though it is nothing but the page file size specified. Infact, that is how it appears in the Performance Options dialog , under virtual memory.

But I am not sure how I get to see 7.82 GB and available VM as 5.80 GB in this server.

Any explanation will be very helpful to understand. Thanks - Mani

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Mani Don't tag "to get as many audiences as possible".

Comment: @Mani - because, and I'm sure you read this in our help files - we APPROPRIATELY tag questions here - so that people who may have genuine 2008 questions can find them, not get spammed by new users who can't be bothered reading what we're about and are asking staggeringly basic questions in the first place even though this site is for professionals and not beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total virtual memory = physical memory + pagefile size

"Virtual memory" refers to the total amount of memory that programs can potentially use on the machine. The pagefile serves as an extension of physical memory, and that's where unused code and data is swapped to in order to free up physical memory for other programs that may need it.

There is less "available" because some of it is already being used by the OS and your running programs.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that tallies it right. But, is there a reason why the physical memory is also taken in to account in indicating the VM size ?

Comment: Get some basic windows training before coming here again.

Comment: @Chopper3 - thanks for your rudeness. I am sure this is already keeping you way down in life and prolly you are living like a lunatic, even if not, very soon you will. Just stay away with your useless comments, if you are not willing to contribute anything useful.

Comment: @Mani - this site is for professionals, not amateurs - and professionals inherently know the basics - such as what the term 'virtual memory' means - it's not my fault you don't know the basics, this isn't a teaching site for those who can't do the tiniest bit of research and who don't even bother to read or observe what the site is about. There was a time when none of us knew this stuff, but then we got training and read about the basics, and that is what I recommended, because if you keep coming here with 'Fisher Price' questions you'll keep getting the same response.

Comment: @Chopper3 - You may assume you are responsible for the big-bang or  think of yourself as an immortal but in a purposeful community filled with inquisitive people, you are worth absolutely nothing. You must see that for yourself, you did nothing useful to answer one's simple question other than being an exhibitionist.                                                                  I humbly repeat my advice for you (as above), just stay away with your useless comments, if you are not willing to contribute anything useful.

Comment: While he did come off as a little tough, he's right that this site is intended for professionals. Your question may have been better suited for (and probably already answered on) Superuser.

Comment: @Mani - *I* contribute here - you do not. Look our respective rep scores - you've asked 3 questions and been downvoted for 2 of them, you've answered ZERO - mine are different from that - is it YOU that are contributing nothing and that's because you can't be bothered to read what this site is about and to adhere to that. You seem to think the site should be about what YOU want it to be - it's not. So don't mention contribution to me - not when I have over SIX THOUSAND times more rep than you FOR HELPING PEOPLE - you have lost a quarter of all the rep you've ever gained by asking bad questions